# Does Amazon Aurora support Updatable Views

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I tried looking online but I couldn't find anything. We are trying to see if Amazon Aurora supports Updatable Views. We are not using Amazon Aurora yet but the plan is to use it in future.

Thanks,
Sridhar.

Comment: Which Aurora platform?  There are two.

Comment: Amazon Aurora RDS

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  RDS Aurora/MySQL or RDS Aurora/PostgreSQL?

Comment: I was under the impression that Aurora has its own database engine but it is also compatible with MySQL or PostgreSQL. If it doesn't, we will probably go with PostgreSQL

Comment: Aurora/MySQL and Aurora/PostgreSQL are two separate products, both of which are based on Amazon's Aurora distributed cluster technology.  It's not possible for a single RDBMS to be compatible with both MySQL and Postgres in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

Because Amazon Aurora implements the Postgres and Mysql engines directly, you can expect all the features of the engine and version that you use on Aurora to work the same way. Updatable views are available in the current database engine versions for both of these engines in Amazon Aurora, and require the same configuration regarding rules and grants as you'd find on a non-Aurora environment.

Postgres engine versions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Updates.20180305.html
Mysql engine versions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.html